# I am getting this error "The Exception type is not generic it can't be parameterized with the argument <ActionEvent>

Tags: java, javafx

```
package mat;

import java.awt.Event;
import java.beans.EventHandler;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.*;
public class myclass extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);   
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg) throws Exception {
            Button btn=new Button("Click Me");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
            });

            StackPane root=new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(btn);
            Scene scene=new Scene(root,500,300);
            arg.setScene(scene);
            arg.show();
    }

}
```

This is the code I run it on Eclipse with the javafx plug-in but it is showing me the error.

Comment: Remove all `java.awt` imports.

Comment: Get rid of all the imports that are obviously wrong (anything with `awt`, since you are using JavaFX, not AWT, and `java.beans.EventHandler`) and replace them with appropriate *JavaFX* imports where needed (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html). Avoid blindly accepting suggestions from your IDE without understanding what they are.